# Array to string conversion php, assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, templates, associative-array

I have a simple Template engine and I have a problem giving it a data from assoc array. Can anybody give me an advice? In method `getStatisticData`, I give an assoc array as first variable `$data`. My input array is in the form:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [OrderNumber] => 1
        [Name] => Zahid
        [Total revenue] => 8363.38
    )
```

I'm trying to get data from it using `foreach` but it doesn't work. I'm getting notice

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Server\htdocs\Task\lib\TemplateGen.php on line 34

```
protected function getStatisticData($data, $template){  

        $text = "";
        if($data === false) {
            return "We don't have any data in database";
        }
        foreach($data as $key => $value){

                $data[$key] = $value;
                $text .= $this->template_gen->getReplaceTemplate($data ,$template);
                }

        return $text;
    }
```

`getReplaceContent` and associated methods from `TemplateGen.php`:

```
 private function getReplaceContent($dataString, $content)
    {
        $search = array();
        $replace = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($dataString as $key => $value) {
            $search[$i] = "%$key%";
            $replace[$i] = $value;
            $i++;
        }
        return str_replace($search, $replace, $content);  ## LINE 34
    }

function getReplaceTemplate($dataString, $template)
    {
        return $this->getReplaceContent($dataString, $this->getTemplate($template));
    }

function getTemplate($name)
    {
        return $content = file_get_contents($this->config->tpl_path . $name . ".tpl");
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I got 2 new errors

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\Server\htdocs\Task\lib\TemplateGen.php on line 28
>   Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_percent() (previously declared in C:\Server\htdocs\Task\lib\TemplateGen.php:25) in C:\Server\htdocs\Task\lib\TemplateGen.php on line 25

Line 25:

```
function add_percent($i) {
```

Line 28:

```
return implode("", str_replace(array_map("add_percent", array_keys($dataString)), array_values($dataString),$content));
```

UPDATE2:
In theory, everything provided in new method should work very well. But there are same problems which were at the beginning

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Server\htdocs\Task\lib\TemplateGen.php on line 44`
>   line 44 :

```
return str_replace(
            array_map($addPercent, array_keys($data)), array_values($data), $template
        );
```

But if I'am using my `getStatisticData` instead of yours, it works but there are many other errors
My method :

```
 protected function getStatisticData($data, $template){

        $text = array();
        if($data === false) {
            return "We don't have any data in database";
        }
        $i=0;
        foreach($data as $dataString){
            if (!empty($data[$i+1])){
            foreach($dataString as $key => $value){
                $dataString[$i][$key] = $dataString[$i][$value];
            }}
            $text .= $this->template_gen->getReplaceTemplate($dataString ,$template);
        }
        return $text;

    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing this: `foreach($data as $key => $value) { $data[$key] = $value;` } ?!

Comment: as mentioned in the above comment, `$data[$key] = $value;` is the same as `$value = $value;` or `$data[$key] = $data[$key];`

Comment: btw, where is line 34 of `TemplateGen`? You have also posted `getReplaceContent`, not `getReplaceTemplate`.

Comment: Updated post with `34 line` and `getReplaceTemplate`

Comment: For the new problems, you're declaring `add_percent` twice. Remove one declaration of the function and see if it works. That might resolve the other error too. Alternatively, you can try the code in my answer below.

Comment: @vladja I've tweaked the code slightly so it should get rid of that error. See update below.

Comment: You've changed `getStatisticData` since you first posted it. You need to define what the expected input and output formats are for your methods and what each method is expected to do. It's almost impossible to deduce from what you have posted (especially when it has changed). i.e. getReplaceContent: arguments: assoc array $data where keys are the strings to replace, values are the replacement strings, and $template is the template to use. returns: string $template with replacements made.

Comment: Added an edited function - check the input and output data and see if that's what you're looking for. If not, you need to clarify what your functions are doing as I mention above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is rather inefficient at present, and it's leading to some isuues. Let's look at the first method you posted:

```
protected function getStatisticData($data, $template){  
    $text = "";
    if($data === false) {
        return "We don't have any data in database";
    }

    foreach($data as $key => $value){

            $data[$key] = $value;
            $text .= $this->template_gen->getReplaceTemplate($data ,$template);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

The `foreach` loop is doing the same thing for each key/value pair (plus `$data[$key] = $value` is redundant as you are already getting each key and value in the `foreach` loop), so you could eliminate the loop, and replace it with something like this:

```
protected function getStatisticData($data, $template){  

    if ($data === false) {
        return "We don't have any data in database";
    }
    return $this->template_gen->getReplaceTemplate($data, $template);
}
```

Similarly for `getReplaceContent` - you're basically using the array keys and array values as the search and the replacement values. You can use PHP's handy [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) instead of building new arrays. The catch is that the array keys need to be surrounded by `%`, but that is easy to do using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) - just define a function that will take in a string and add `%` to either end of it, and then `array_map` it to your array keys:

```
private function getReplaceContent($data, $template)
{
    $addPercent = function( $i ){
        return "%$i%";
    };

    return str_replace( 
        array_map( $addPercent, array_keys($data)), array_values($data), $template
    );
}
```

Now, calling `getStatisticData` will return the template text with all the replaced data in it.

Sample input:

```
$arr = array(
    'OrderNumber' => 1,
    'Name' => 'Zahid',
    'Total revenue' => '8363.38'
);

$template =
'<p>Name: %Name%<br>
Total revenue: %Total revenue%<br>
Order number: %OrderNumber%</p>';
```

Output of `getStatisticData`:

```
<p>Name: Zahid<br>
Total revenue: 8363.38<br>
Order number: 1</p>
```

**EDIT:** it is not clear from the OP what the input to `getStatisticData` is, but it looks like it is supposed to be an array of associative arrays. If this is so, the code for `getStatisticData` should be altered as follows:

```
protected function getStatisticData($dataArray, $template){  

    if ($dataArray === false) {
        return "We don't have any data in database";
    }
    $text = "";
    foreach ($dataArray as $aa) {
        $text .= $this->template_gen->getReplaceTemplate($aa, $template);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Sample input:

```
$arr = 
[
    [   'OrderNumber' => 1,
        'Name' => 'Zahid',
        'Total revenue' => '8363.38'
    ],
    [   'OrderNumber' => 2,
        'Name' => 'Paul',
        'Total revenue' => '123.45'
    ],
    [   'OrderNumber' => 3,
        'Name' => 'Jane',
        'Total revenue' => '567.89'
    ],
];
```

Output:

```
<p>Name: Zahid<br> 
Total revenue: 8363.38<br>
Order number: 1</p>
<p>Name: Paul<br> 
Total revenue: 123.45<br>
Order number: 2</p>
<p>Name: Jane<br> 
Total revenue: 567.89<br>
Order number: 3</p>
```

Comment: hmm, really interesting decision, didn't know about this way.But it's problem right now, server doesn't want to load something with new methods, it's infinite loading right now

Comment: You'll have to edit one or more of your methods if you want the code to work, unfortunately!

Comment: The two functions at the bottom of my answer will work as drop-in replacements -- you can comment out your old functions and put those two in in their places, and they should solve the array-to-string problem you were having. `:)`

Comment: please, see 2 errors(update2), which came after using the code you provided. Have any ideas how to repair it?

Comment: I am about to go offline - will check in the AM.

Comment: @vladja I've changed the code to use a closure instead of creating the function `add_function`. This works on input data like the array you posted -- I've added an example of the input and output from the function.

Comment: Oh My God, I tried so many different `foreach` loop variant, but it was so easy. Thank you very much, you are awesome!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the associative array $data has simply strings in it. I'm assuming that the $data array has its keys as the template placeholder and the value as the value to input.

If so, and if you're trying to get a single string, then consider doing this:

```
protected function getStatisticData($data, $template) {
    if ($data === false) {
        return "We don't have any data in the database.";
    }
    return this->template_gen->getReplaceTemplate($data, $template);
}

private function getReplaceContent($dataString, $content) {
    content = '';
    foreach ($dataString as $key => $value) {
        $content .= str_replace("%{$key}%", $value, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

You don't need quite as many `foreach` loops. One should do just fine.